On Android, how to check if an internet address is reachable?
I'm rewriting an old application for Android written with Delphi XE. In short, this application connects to the server (IP address + port number), sends an SQL request, and processes the received data.
Sometimes, the server is down and the application "freezes" for several seconds (even minutes) before showing a "server problem" message. Now, I need to check if the given IP address is reachable (if the server is offline for any reason, the application will stop).
I tried to use some answer(s) found here without any result:
Android - Checking internet connection by pinging url
Delphi XE6 and Android Ping
Android - Check internet connection by pinging url address
Is there any solution without using a raw socket under Delphi 11.x?

Why don't you simply move your network code from main thread to secondary thread so waiting for server response doesn't block the UI. Checking server availability by pinging it doesn't verify that server is prepared to process your data.

Delhi is pretty popular here.

Pinging the IP is really a TOCTOU race condition, since the server could still go down after you ping it and before you connect to it.  Best to just connect to it unconditionally and handle any failure.

@Remy - You have rigth, i try connection and wait for response .... Thank's to all
